# ITextSharp setting background working not for all fields

Tags: c#, itext

I have the following string of code setting bacground for all pdf fields:

```
 using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(template))
 {
     using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)){FormFlattening = true})
     {
          var fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
          foreach (var field in fields.Fields)
          {
             fields.SetFieldProperty(field.Key, "bgcolor", new BaseColor(Color.Red), null);
          }
     }
 }
```

However, the problem is that background is being set not for all fields, just for some of them. I debugged, and the method is being run for all fields, and returning true every time. Fields are having exact same properties (only name is different). I ran out of ideas, somebody pls help.

Comment: Show us the PDF. Tell us which version of iTextSharp you're using (maybe it's a mighty old version that doesn't support what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but after 4 hours trying I figured it out. It's not filling fields having no value. So you have to put at least String.Empty as a value, and background is getting filled after that. May be it will be useful and will save couple of hours for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a field property, after you changed it, you have to regenerate the field for making the edit effective . http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-change-text-color-acroform-field

```
 Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream(BASE_PATH + inputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream(BASE_PATH + outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    Document doc = new Document();

    doc.Open();
    var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, outputPdfStream);
    AcroFields af = stamper.AcroFields;


    if (colorInfos != null && colorInfos.Count > 0)
    {
        af.SetField("color_level_title", colorInfos[""]);
        af.SetField("color_level_up_title", colorInfos[""]);
        af.SetField("color_level_low_title", colorInfos[""]);


    }
    af.SetFieldProperty("hide_low_content", "bgcolor", BaseColor.WHITE, null);
    af.RegenerateField("hide_low_content");
    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    stamper.Close();


}
```

Comment: Where is this BaseColor enum or class?